# How to calculate $p_i$ in Blau's Index of Heterogeneity

Tags: statistics, economics

I came across this:

"Therefore, board gender diversity and board racial diversity are calculated using Blau's index of heterogeneity $(1 - \sum p_{i}^2)$, where $p_i$ is the proportion of group members in each of the $i$ categories."

I'd like to know, if the category just includes $2$ (male and female) then how can I calculate Blau's Index? How can I calculate $p_i$?

For example, if ten men and ten women in total, what is the index?

Sorry, English is not my first language.

Comment: Welcome! What are you summing over? Should the $\pi$ have a subscript $i$ and is the $\pi$ supposed to squared i.e. what is the 2 after $\pi$?

Comment: It's not the constant of Pi, it's just P and i. The 2 is supposed to be superscripted. I postes this question on behalf of a Chinese friend but she figured it out now. Sorry for the unclear question.

Comment: The answer is: If there are ten in total, 3 women and the rest men then you get 3x3+7x7=58. Then 58/(10x10). 1-0.58 which means the Index is 0.42.

Answer (score 0):

The Blau Index of Heterogeneity is present in a footnote of:

> Blau, P.M., 1977. Inequality and Heterogeneity: A Primitive Theory of Social Structure, First Edition. ed. Free Pr, London.

(page 9, footnote 2).

In reality Blau did not invent it. In that footnote, he says that "the measure of heterogeneity is" and provides the formula.

But in reality the index was already present at least in:

> Gibbs, J.P., Poston, D.L., Jr., 1975. The Division of Labor: Conceptualization and Related Measures. Social Forces 53, 468–476. https://doi.org/10.1093/sf/53.3.468

and is called "M1" there.

It is defined as:

$M1 = 1 - \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2}{(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i)^2} = 1 - \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2}{N^2} = 1 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \dfrac{x_i^2}{N^2} = 1 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \left(\dfrac{x_i}{N}\right)^2 = 1 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^k p_i^2$

Where $k$ is the number of classes (e.g. gender, race, functions (marketing, sales, production,...), education (elementary school, high school, college, ...)) in which people could be classified, $x_i$ is the number of people in class $i$, $N=\sum_{i=1}^k x_i$ is the total number of people, and $p_i=\dfrac{x_i}{N}$ is the fraction of people in class $i$.

If all the people are in class $a$, and no persons are in classes other than $a$, then $x_a=N$ and $x_i=0 \forall i \neq a$. Then $p_a=1$ and $p_i=0 \forall i \neq a$. Then:

$M1 = 1 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^k p_i^2 = 1 - 1 = 0$.

Instead, if persons are equally distributed among classes, then $x_i = \dfrac{N}{k} \forall i$ and $p_i = \dfrac{x_i}{N} = \dfrac{N}{k} \dfrac{1}{N} = \dfrac{1}{k} $ and:

$M1 = 1 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^k p_i^2 = 1 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \left(\dfrac{1}{k}\right)^2 = 1 - k \left(\dfrac{1}{k}\right)^2 = 1 - \dfrac{1}{k} = \dfrac{k-1}{k} $

which tends to 1 as $k \to +\infty$.

$M1$ is then a measure of diversity, and ranges from $0$ in case the group is maximally homogeneous (all persons belong to the same class) to $\dfrac{k-1}{k}$ in case the group is maximally heterogeneous (are classes are equally represented, that is, all persons are equally distributed among the classes).

Answer (score -1):

Blau's Index calls for adding the squared proportion of individuals in each category, summing them up, then subtracting from 1.  In the example of two individuals, half (.5) are male and half (.5) are female.  .5<sup>2</sup> is .25.  Add .25 and .25 to obtain .5.  Subtract this from 1 and you have a diversity index of .5.  The proportions are the same when there are ten females and ten males so the answer would be the same.  However, different proportions such as 3 females and 7 males do result in a different answer.  .3<sup>2</sup> is .09 and .7<sup>2</sup> is .49.  Added together we have .58 to subtract from 1 and a diversity index of .42. P<sub>i</sub> represents each category's proportion with each proportion (.5 and .5 or .3 and .7 in the respective examples).